# How do I update a record that has a child entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update a record and its child at the same time.  When I create the object from the database the child property is null (the property is a generic list).

I want to update the class and also update the child class without creating duplicated records in the system.

Here is how I generate the object:

```
var r = db.SupplierAs.Where(o => o.id == 1).First();
```

The SupplierA class has a property List.  Using the above line of code this comes back `null`.  I have been trying work out the code to initialize this property so I can update it but I am having no joy.

This is the original item I created:

```
        db.Products.Add(new Product
        {
            name = "product test",
            supplierA = new SupplierA
            {
                name = "supA",
                price = 1.99m,
                sku = "abc123",
                otherCurrencies = new List<Currency>
                {
                    new Currency 
                    {
                        eur = 2.99m,
                        usd = 3.99m

                    }
                }
            },

        });
        db.SaveChanges();
```

I can update the supplier on its own easily like so:

```
var r = db.SupplierAs.Where(o => o.id == 1).First();
r.name = "Updated name";
db.SupplierAs.Attach(r);
db.Entry(r).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

But I cannot figure out how to generate the Currency object list as part of the SupplierAs object.  Currencies doesnt seem to be in the db context.

Here are the class files:

```
public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual SupplierA supplierA { get; set; }
}
public class SupplierA
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public List<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
}
public class Currency
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public decimal eur { get; set; }
    public decimal usd { get; set; }
}
```

The idea of products, suppliers and currencies doesn't make the greatest sense I know, I have extracted logic from my app in example, hopefully it makes enough sense what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What *exactly* do you do and in which order? You "generate", "create", and "update", but when? Also, do any Currencies ever get saved? Or is the only problem that Currencies are duplicated, while you want to connect a supplier to existing currencies?

Comment: I just run the add snippet once to create entry in database.  Then afterwards I try to update.  Sorry my post was non linear, I just thought it would be easier to explain main issue first.  Currencies are created when I first create Product object (I only do this once). When I initialize the SupplierA object to update it, Currencies is null and I don't know how to initialize it so it does not get updated when I update SupplierA. I also cannot figure out how to update currencies on their own as they don't seem to be accessible through dbcontext

Comment: Use `db.SupplierAs.Include(s => s.Currencies).Where...`

Comment: what am I trying the specify in the where?  The SupllierA_id property is not visible to me in intellisense (but exists in database)

Comment: ahh ok i see what you mean. This works: `var r = db.SupplierAs.Where(o => o.id == 1).Include("Currencies").First();`   It is initialized so I figure it will save.  Thank you very much for helping me, that was really confusing me